# Ignore a column based on where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Edit:

So, it seems there is some confusion in specifically what I want to do, so I am going to alter my example.

I have a table named example_table:

```
id       code1      code2
-------------------------
1        1780       4245
2        1781       4280
3        1900       1200
4        2800       4217
5        2817       1782
```

With this, I want to find something like,

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE code1 LIKE '%17%' OR code2 LIKE '%17%';
```

I want this to return

```
id      code1      code2
------------------------
1       1780       null
2       1781       null
4       null       4217
5       2817       1782
```

So you'll notice it nulls any result that doesn't match from either column, and if both are present it will grab both.

Comment: What if Susie's maiden name was `Walker`, and you were searching for `Walker`?  What would the resultset be?  Clearly both Susie and Johnny should be returned, but with what columns: `first_name` and ...?

Comment: @eggyal It should have: Johnny Walker and Susie Walker, leaving out the Smith on Susie. If Susie's last name was also Walker, both should be included.

Comment: I get that, but what would the name of that second column be? It's neither `last_name` nor `maiden_name`, as it's a mix of both.  In fact, it contains only the value `Smith` for everyone, so let's just call it `Smith`.  Or why include it at all?

Comment: Because I won't be doing a perfect =, I'll be doing a like. So there are other combinations possible.

Comment: @JAM - You do realise that you've fundamentally changed your question?  This means that the answers below now do not relate to the question.  So, anyone coming to this question in the future won't be seeing what they should.  I'll update my answer to reflect the new question, but it would have been better to ask a new question rather than completely changing one with existing answers.

Comment: @Dems Yes, I know. I was debating whether or not to create a new question or just edit this one. In the future I will ask a new question if the edit would change the meaning significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL code should do it for you

```
SELECT
    A.id,B.code1,C.code2
FROM
    (SELECT id FROM example_table) A
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT id,code1 FROM example_table
        WHERE code1 LIKE '%17%'
    ) B ON A.id=B.id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT id,code2 FROM example_table
        WHERE code2 LIKE '%17%'
    ) C ON A.id=C.id
WHERE
    ISNULL(B.code1) = 0 OR ISNULL(C.code1) = 0
;
```

I cannot make any promises on performance for it.

If you do not mind presenting null as a string, try this one:

```
SELECT
    id,
    IF(code1 LIKE '%17%',code1,'null') code1,
    IF(code2 LIKE '%17%',code2,'null') code2
FROM example_table WHERE
    code1 LIKE '%17%' OR
    code2 LIKE '%17%';
```

One full table scan with no joins. This may be better.

Comment: Getting very, very close. Right now I have the if statement on `id` as well. This still returns the row, but with all Null values. If all the values (or `code1` and `code2` are null), I don't want that row at all.

Comment: As per the edit to my answer (from before this answer was posted); you don't need the NULLs to be strings.

Answer (score 5):

Literally, you could do something like this...

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  CASE WHEN last_name = 'Smith' THEN last_name ELSE maiden_name END
FROM
  users
WHERE
     last_name   = 'Smith'
  OR maiden_name = 'Smith'
```

But, actually, whatever field matches, it'll be 'Smith', so why bother, just do this?

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  'Smith'
FROM
  users
WHERE
     last_name   = 'Smith'
  OR maiden_name = 'Smith'
```

**EDIT:** Based on your editted question...

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE WHEN code1 LIKE '%17%' THEN code1 ELSE NULL END AS code1,
  CASE WHEN code2 LIKE '%17%' THEN code2 ELSE NULL END AS code2
FROM
  example_table
WHERE
     code1 LIKE '%17%'
  OR code2 LIKE '%17%'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this elegantly with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE last_name='Smith'
    UNION
SELECT first_name, maiden_name FROM users WHERE maiden_name='Smith';
```

or somewhat less elegantly with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT first_name, 
    CASE WHEN last_name='Smith' THEN last_name
    ELSE maiden_name END
    AS last_name
FROM users where last_name='Smith' or maiden_name='Smith';
```

which as [@Dems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838862/166339) points out, can be simplified to:

```
SELECT first_name, 'Smith' AS last_name
FROM users WHERE last_name='Smith' or maiden_name='Smith';
```

which begs the question, do you really even need `last_name` in your result set at all? The caller already knows the `last_name` because it's part of the query. Why not return only the `first_name` and have a very simple, easy to understand query?

```
SELECT first_name FROM users
WHERE last_name='Smith' or maiden_name='Smith';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  IF(last_name='Smith',last_name,concat(last_name,' (née ',maiden_name,')')) AS last_name
FROM
  users
WHERE
  users.last_name='Smith'
  OR maiden_name='Smith'
```